# Extending a domain of a function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Suppose $f: (a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and continuous on its domain, where $a, b \in R$, and assume there exists $M > 0$ such that $|f'(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in (a, b)$.

Using the Mean Value Theorem, prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a, b]$.

I do not need help with the last bit, I can see how it works once the conditions for MVT are satisfied.

I'm trying to determine if the Mean Value Theorem can be used here. Is it possible to say that the function is continuous on $[a, b]$?

Comment: The question makes no sense, since the domain of $f$ is $(a,b)$, not on $[a,b]$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos well the full question states that $f'(x)$ is bounded on the domain. We're then asked to use the Mean Value Theorem to determine if it is uniformly continuous. But the theorem is viable when the function is continuous on [a, b]

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah: Your example shows that the function must not "grow too much" near the endpoints of the interval. The assumption about $f$ having bounded derivative on $(a,b)$ is one way to make that precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question does not exactly "parse" as was pointed out in the comments since $f$ is only defined on $(a,b)$, but there is a natural question that is implied by the given wording. What I believe the question wants you to show is that there is an extension $\tilde f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ of $f$ such that $\tilde f$ is uniformly continuous. That $\tilde f$ is an extension of $f$ means $\tilde f(x) = f(x)$ for all $x\in (a,b)$.

To help you get started on addressing this question, a necessary condition for such an extension to exist is that $L_a:=\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ and $L_b:=\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)$ exist. Provided that $L_a, L_b$ exist, the **only** possible such extension $\tilde f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ must be given by
$$\tilde f(x) = \begin{cases} L_a &\text{if $x = a$,}\\f(x) & \text{if $x\in(a,b)$,}\\L_b &\text{if $x = b$}.\end{cases}$$
Continuity of $\tilde f$ is immediate from its definition, so it is up to you to prove the critical fact that $L_a,L_b$ exist (so $\tilde f$ is well-defined) and that $\tilde f$ is uniformly continuous. You may use the mean value theorem to prove that $L_a,L_b$ exist. In your proof, you cannot make reference to $f(a)$ or $f(b)$, since $f$ is not defined at $a$ or $b$ *a priori*, and indeed, this is essentially the point of the exercise.

As a remark about the question itself, I would venture that the fact that $\tilde f$ is the **unique** extension of $f$ to $[a,b]$ with the property of being uniformly continuous is the reason the question was worded the way it was.

Comment: I'm curious, it is necessary to use MVT to prove $L_{a}$ and $L_{b}$ exist? Since our extension is continuous on [a, b], a compact set, then the range of that same function is also a compact set.

Therefore every sequence in the range converges to a limit also in f($[a, b]$).

Comment: @Malcolm: we can’t talk about $\tilde f$ or use its properties (like that it is continuous or has compact range) until we prove it is *well-defined.* As I said in my answer, this amounts precisely to proving that $L_a,L_b$ exist. The assumption about $f$ having bounded derivative is convenient for proving these limits exist—it amounts to the uniform continuity of $f$ on $(a,b)$.

Comment: Ok. I see I was using circular logic there, thank you. But you mentioned using the MVT to prove the limits exist. How would one do that?

Comment: For say $L_{b}$ we know that $|f'(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in (a, b)$ so $|f'(b)| \leq M$ then $\lim_{x \to b^{-}} |\frac{f(x) - L_{b}}{b - x}|$

Comment: Then we have $\lim_{x \to b^{-}} |f(x) - L_{b}| \leq lim_{x \to b^{-}} M|x - b|$. So for any abitrary $\epsilon > 0$ we choose $\delta = \epsilon/2M$ then the limit exists.

Comment: @Malcolm: I think you are on the right track, but you can't put $L_b$ into expressions before proving it exists. To prove a limit exists, you typically have to think of Cauchy sequences. I am suggesting you combine this idea with the mean value theorem somehow.

Comment: Ok. Suppose $(x_{n})$ is sequence in $(a, b)$ that converges to b. Then $(x_{n})$ is a cauchy sequence. We need to show the sequence $(f(x_{n}))$ converges. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Let $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2M}$ we know that $|x_{n} - x_{m}| < \delta$ for past a certain point and that $f' \leq M$ which implies $\frac{|f(x_{n}) - f(x_{m})|}{|x_{n} - x_{m}|} \leq M$. Which given our $\delta$ means that $(f(x_{n}))$ is a cauchy sequence, thus it converges.

Comment: Since it converges, the limit exists.

Comment: @Malcolm: Good. You don't need to mention that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, the main point is that you proved $(f(x_n))$ converges, and we may call the limit $L_b$. Note that you need the mean value theorem (applied to $x_n$ and $x_m$) to conclude that $|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|/|x_n-x_m|\le M$. Now that $L_b$ is defined, we can define an extension of $f$ to $(a,b]$. Similar argumentation allows you to extend $f$ to $[a,b]$.

Comment: Right, but by the Continuous Extension theorem, since $f$ can be extended to $[a, b]$ it is uniformly continuous on $(a, b)$...but I still have to use MVT to show that it is uniformly continuous huh?

Comment: @Malcolm: I am not familiar with the statement of that theorem, but it is true that if you have a continuous function on a closed interval $[a,b]$, then it is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$. Whether this requires an additional proof, or you take it as a given is up to you, but hopefully you see the main point of the exercise is proving that there exists an extension. The wording of the question also implies that it wants you to know there is a **unique** extension, which justifies using the same letter $f$ for the function and its extension.

Comment: Thank you! The theorem states that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a, b)$ if and only if it is possible to define the values of $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ at the endpoints so that the extended function is continuous on $[a, b]$